# Recursive Function javascript to show nested json object but the variable is getting printed multiple times

Tags: javascript, json

Hi i'm trying to append the values from JSON nested object to a table but the values(content) are being appended multiple times because of the recursive function.i just need the value to be displayed once but the recursive function keeps on adding values in the content variable .any help would be appreciated
This is my full code [output shows (chris and steve) data multiple times][1]

```
 /* Javascript */
// This function will execute when JQuery is fully loaded
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Send a message to the console
  console.log("JQuery is ready!");

  // Get the JSON data from the API
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://airbly.com/webdevjob/api.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      console.log("We got the JSON data!");
      //var text =JSON.stringify(data, null, '  ');
      display_json(data);
      //var x = 
     // $("table").append('<th>'+'Customer'+'</th>'+'<th>'+'Order date'+'</th>'+'<th>'+' Quantity'+'</th>')

    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
  });
});

function timeConverter(UNIX_timestamp) { // Function to resolve the unix timestamp
  var a = new Date(UNIX_timestamp * 1000);
  var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
  var year = a.getFullYear();
  var month = months[a.getMonth()];
  var date = a.getDate();
  var time = date + ' ' + month + ' ' + year; 
  return time;
}

function display_json(data) { //Recursive  Function to retrive the nested object values
  var content =  '<tr>'; 
  $.each(data, function(i, post) { // Iterating over the JSON Object where i = key and post = value
    if (post !== null && typeof post == 'object') { // for nested object
      content += display_json(post); //calling the display_json () again on the nested object
    } 
    else {
      switch(i){

         case 'image' :     var img = document.createElement("IMG");
                            img.src = post;
                            $('#details').append(img);
                            break;


        case 'partnumber' : var pnbr = '<b>' + "Part number" +'</b>'  +" "+":" +" "+ post + '</br>'; 
                            $('#details').append(pnbr);
                            break;


        case 'name' :       var name = '<b>' + "Name" +" "+ '</b>' +":"+" " + post + '</br>' ; 
                            $('#details').append(name);
                            break;


        case 'when' :       var tme = timeConverter(post); // Calling the timeConverter(); to convert the unix time stamp to the appropriate time
                            content += '<td>' + tme + '</td>'; // adding the converted time to the table data
                            break;

        default     :      
                            if(post == '1' || post == '2' || post == 'orders' ){
                            //console.log(post);
                                                }
                            else{
                              content += '<td>' + post + '</td>';
                              //count++;
                            }
    }
    } 

  });
  content += '</tr>';
  console.log(content);
  $("table").append(content);
  return content; // returning the content value  
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwW25.png
```

Comment: Getting a look at your data might paint a better picture. Looking at your code though, nothing seems immediately wrong to me. Minor improvement: `if (post !== null && typeof post == 'object')` can just be: `if (typeof post === 'object')`. null can never be an object :)

Comment: <tr><td>Chris</td><td>1 Sep 2015</td><td>400</td></tr>
<tr><td>Steve</td><td>1 Oct 2015</td><td>36</td></tr>
<tr><tr><td>Chris</td><td>1 Sep 2015</td><td>400</td></tr><tr><td>Steve</td><td>1 Oct 2015</td><td>36</td></tr></tr>
run:170 <tr><tr><tr><td>Chris</td><td>1 Sep 2015</td><td>400</td></tr><tr><td>Steve</td><td>1 Oct 2015</td><td>36</td></tr></tr></tr>

Comment: Ah my bad, i missed the url at the top :). I usually skip those as most people put "example.com".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must be doing something wrong in how you're using ajax. Had to fix a couple syntax errors in your pasted code, but i managed to get this to run in a fiddle.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://airbly.com/webdevjob/api.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        console.log(display_json(data));
    }
});

function display_json(data) { //Recursive  Function to retrive the nested object values
  var content =  '<tr>'; 
  $.each(data, function(i, post) { // Iterating over the JSON Object where i = key and post = value
    if (post !== null && typeof post == 'object') { // for nested object
      content += display_json(post); //calling the display_json () again on the nested object
    } 
    else {
      switch(i){
         case 'image' :
          var img = document.createElement("IMG");
          img.src = post;
          $('#details').append(img);
          break;


        case 'partnumber' : 
          var pnbr = '<b>' + "Part number" +'</b>'  +" "+":" +" "+ post + '</br>'; 
          $('#details').append(pnbr);
          break;


        case 'name' :      
          var name = '<b>' + "Name" +" "+ '</b>' +":"+" " + post + '</br>' ; 
          $('#details').append(name);
          break;


        case 'when' :
          // var tme = timeConverter(post)
          content += '<td>' + post + '</td>'; // adding the converted time to the table data
          break;

        default     :      
          if(post == '1' || post == '2' || post == 'orders' ){
          //console.log(post);
                              }
          else{
            content += '<td>' + post + '</td>';
            //count++;
          }
      }
    }
  });
  content += '</tr>';
  return content; // returning the content value  
}
```

Output of the console.log:

`<tr><tr><tr><td>Chris</td><td>1441129302</td><td>400</td></tr><tr><td>Steve</td><td>1443721302</td><td>36</td></tr></tr></tr>`

Comment: hi could you look at the updated code and output image.thanks

Comment: thanks it helped your console statement gave me the idea                      var content=display_json(data);
      $("table").append(content);